# Sequelize Typescript Associations Types

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an app using Sequelize v6 and Typescript, but I need help with how associations M:N work in the new Sequelize implementation for Typescript.

I have the following code:

```js
interface UserModel
    extends Model<
        InferAttributes<UserModel>,
        InferCreationAttributes<UserModel>
    > {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
}

const User = sequelize.define<UserModel>(
    "User",
    {
        first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
        underscored: true,
    }
);

interface ProgramModel
    extends Model<
        InferAttributes<ProgramModel>,
        InferCreationAttributes<ProgramModel>
    > {
    name: string;
}
const Program = sequelize.define<ProgramModel>(
    "Program",
    {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    { underscored: true }
);

interface UserProgramModel
    extends Model<
        InferAttributes<UserProgramModel>,
        InferCreationAttributes<UserProgramModel>
    > {
    medic_id: number;
}
const UserProgram = sequelize.define<UserProgramModel>(
    "UserProgram",
    {
        medic_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    { underscored: true }
);

UserProgram.belongsTo(User);
UserProgram.belongsTo(Program);
```

And I'm trying to execute this query `UserProgram.findByPk(id, { include: [User, Program] })`

But when I check the autosuggestions of the result of that query, I'm getting the default `Model` methods like `.destroy` and the `UserProgramModel` attributes `medic_id`.

Is this the expected behavior, and if so, how do I access the `Users` and `Programs` attributes?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So Anatoly's answer was partially correct, your answer guided me throughout the documentation, and I found this:

```js
// You can also pre-declare possible inclusions, these will only be populated if you
  // actively include a relation.
  declare projects?: NonAttribute<Project[]>; // Note this is optional since it's only populated when explicitly requested in code
```

Although this example appears in the `class` example, it also applies to the `sequelize.define` implementation.

So the final model interface would be:

```js
interface UserProgramModel
    extends Model<
        InferAttributes<UserProgramModel>,
        InferCreationAttributes<UserProgramModel>
    > {
    medic_id: number;
    User?: NonAttribute<UserModel>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add all props that correspond all used associations:

```js
interface UserProgramModel
    extends Model<
        InferAttributes<UserProgramModel>,
        InferCreationAttributes<UserProgramModel>
    > {
    medic_id: number;
    user: UserModel;
    program: ProgramModel;
}
```